# redirecting to codeigniter controller using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, codeigniter-2

This is the url

```
http://rapidsurfing.net/visio/xip8yT
```

My site is developed in codeigniter. So when link this above url I want to go to one controller function. How can I do this using htaccess.

This is my httaccces code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^p\/(.*)$ page.php?q=$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?admin/index/url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The `url` have value `xip8yT`.The `admin` is the controller name and `index` is the function in that controller.

But when I paste the url `http://rapidsurfing.net/visio/xip8yT` in address bar it load 404 not found error.
What is the problem or mistake in my code?
My default controller is admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you set up your default controller in `routes.php` file. A complete answer to your question is the way that I worked with CI. CodeIginter itself recommend to use a `.htaccess` for redirecting all of requests to your index page and your default controller and it's what you did. But I recommend to use this piece of code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /yourbasefoldername

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(yourdefaultcontrollername(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/dfgamez/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/dfgamez/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Simply you'll get every slashes after the site address to your `index` function parameters.

Peace Out!

Comment: i also set my default controller as admin

Comment: Is it on your localhost or the main host? make sure if your application is on the main host remove the RewriteBase like this: `RewriteBase /` without any name. The error must be occur in case that you programmed wrong code or not configured a part of CI correctly. BTW, set your `$config['base_url']` in the `config.php` file to empty.

Comment: no it is in main host.In main host there have a directory visio that is the root folder of my site.The error still same displayed

Comment: So the base URL should be `RewriteBase /visio`. I don't know what's exactly the problem. My opinion is to write a simple application with focusing on this problem and do a try and error for yourself to find out the way of implementation of your address. BTW, I recommend the CI forums, it have fully informed users. http://codeigniter.com/forums/